# Como criar objetos dinamicamente com base em vetor? (VBA/Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Criei duas Labels dinamicamente com base em um vetor conforme o código abaixo, porém, no formulário só permanece a última Label criada (NewLabel1), tanto a primeira (NewLabel0) como a Label que usei de base para a criação das outras duas (Label1) não permanecem.

Preciso criar várias Labels conforme o número de itens que quero trabalhar (uma para cada produto de certa linha de cosméticos, por exemplo), por isso a necessidade de usar um vetor. Como posso resolver isso?

```
Dim NewLabel(1) As Object

Set NewLabel(0) = Label1 'Label1 existe no formulário
Set NewLabel(1) = Label1

With NewLabel(0)
 .Caption = "NewLabel0"
 .Top = 0
 .Left = 0
End With

With NewLabel(1)
 .Caption = "NewLabel1"
 .Top = 20
 .Left = 20
End With

...
...
...

NewLabel(0).Delete
NewLabel(1).Delete
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numa altura que precisei usei este código, verifica se consegues adaptar para ti.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
i = 1
maxBoxes = 3
    For idx = 1 To maxBoxes
            Set newBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
            With newBox
                .Tag = "new" & .Name
                    .Left = 55 * idx
                    .Top = 10
                    .Width = 50
                    .Text = "Exemplo" & i
            End With

            Set newBox1 = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "txt-" & i)
            With newBox1
                .Tag = "new" & .Name
                    .Left = 55 * idx
                    .Top = 25
                    .Width = 50
            End With
            i = i + 1
        Next
End Sub
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Funcionou muito bem! Abaixo a adaptação sugerida para o meu caso (usando vetor). Grato!

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim NewLabel(3) As Object

For i = 0 To 3
 Set NewLabel(i) = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
 With NewLabel(i)
  .Tag = "NewLabel" & i 'Usar no lugar de "Name"
  .Caption = .Tag 'Name inicia do Label2 pois existe o Label1 no formulário
  .Top = 50 * i
  .Left = 50
End With

Next i
```